# Is it possible to get the names and values of the members of an enum in D?

Tags: reflection, d

I would like to get the names and values from an `enum` type in D2. I know I can get enum values using std.traits but what about the names?

Given:

```
enum lst
{
  apple,
  bottle,
  orange,
  blue    
}
```

I would like to get an associative array like.

```
string lstmap[int] = [1:"apple", 2:"bottle", 3:"orange", 4:"blue"].
```

---

The answer is yes. The solution, as someone showed me is:

```
foreach (i, member; __traits(allMembers, lst)) {
  lstmap[cast(int) __traits(getMember, lst, member)] = member;
}
```

Comment: Could you please submit the answer yourself and mark it as accepted, so that the question no longer shows up as unanswered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
foreach (i, member; __traits(allMembers, lst)) {
  lstmap[cast(int) __traits(getMember, lst, member)] = member;
}
```

(copied from question as community wiki)

Answer (score 2):

In case you want this solely for purposes of value-to-string convertation, consider using `std.conv.to!string(lst.orange)` — will evaluate to `"orange"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
      //ENUMList is the name of Enum

        var values = (ENUMList[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ENUMList));
        var query = from name in values
                    select new EnumData//EnumData is a Modal or Entity
                    {
                        ID = (short)name,
                        Name = GetEnumDescription(name)//Description of Particular Enum Name
                    };
        return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer is for C#, not D